# Duplicate a function on jquery

Tags: jquery, popup, slide

I found this slide pop up jquery function:

```
function openOffersDialog() {

    $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('#boxpopup').css('display','block');
        $('#boxpopup').animate({'left':'30%'},500);
    });
}


    function closeOffersDialog(prospectElementID) {
        $(function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','absolute');
                $('#' + prospectElementID).animate({'left':'-100%'}, 500, function() {
                    $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','fixed');
                    $('#' + prospectElementID).css('left','100%');
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

and here is the html

```
<body onload="openOffersDialog();">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
<a onclick="openOffersDialog();">Click Here To See The PopUp</a>
<div id="boxpopup" class="box">
    <a onclick="closeOffersDialog('boxpopup');" class="boxclose"></a>
    <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

So how can I duplicate that function so I can use it in 2 or more links on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function so that you sent in the IDs of the elements to use:

```
function openOffersDialog(overlay, popup) {
  $('#' + overlay).fadeIn('fast', function() {
    $('#' + popup).css('display','block');
    $('#' + popup).animate({'left':'30%'},500);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
openOffersDialog('overlay', 'boxpopup');
```

Add the ID of the overlay to the closing function:

```
function closeOffersDialog(prospectElementID, overlay) {
  $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','absolute');
  $('#' + prospectElementID).animate({'left':'-100%'}, 500, function() {
    $('#' + prospectElementID).css('position','fixed');
    $('#' + prospectElementID).css('left','100%');
    $('#' + overlay).fadeOut('fast');
  });
}
```

Note: the closing function had code to bind a `ready` event, with an event handler which contained code to bind a `ready` event, with an event handler which contained the actual code to execute. When you bind the `ready` event after the event has happened, jQuery will just execute the event handler immediately, so that's why that code worked at all. The function should of course not bind the `ready` event at all.

Usage:

```
closeOffersDialog('boxpopup', 'overlay');
```

Now. to use it in more places, make overlay and popup elements with different IDs, and call the functions with those instead.

Answer (score -1):

it's call multiple function using at one time like ajax panel you can also use this for slide